# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Core" 7.0.0

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic-framework, capacitor

following scenario:

Ionic app with capacitor and ios platform.
After updating firebase package via npm from 7 to 8 the ios version breaks when doing 'ionic cap build ios'

**Error:**

```
✖ Updating iOS native dependencies with "pod install" (may take several minutes): 
✖ update ios: 
[error] Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Analytics":
  In Podfile:
    CordovaPluginsStatic (from `../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins`) was resolved to 2.4.7, which depends on
      Firebase/Analytics (~> 7.0.0)

    Firebase/Analytics

CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Core":
  In Podfile:
    CapacitorFirebaseAuth (from `../../node_modules/capacitor-firebase-auth`) was resolved to 2.4.0, which depends on
      Firebase/Core

    CordovaPluginsStatic (from `../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins`) was resolved to 2.4.7, which depends on
      Firebase/Analytics (~> 7.0.0) was resolved to 7.0.0, which depends on
        Firebase/Core (= 7.0.0)

CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseCore":
  In Podfile:
    CordovaPluginsStatic (from `../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins`) was resolved to 2.4.7, which depends on
      Firebase/RemoteConfig (~> 7.0.0) was resolved to 7.0.0, which depends on
        Firebase/CoreOnly (= 7.0.0) was resolved to 7.0.0, which depends on
          FirebaseCore (= 7.0.0)

    CordovaPluginsStatic (from `../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins`) was resolved to 2.4.7, which depends on
      Firebase/RemoteConfig (~> 7.0.0) was resolved to 7.0.0, which depends on
        FirebaseRemoteConfig (~> 7.0.0) was resolved to 7.0.0, which depends on
          FirebaseCore (~> 7.0)

    FirebaseCore

CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler":
  In Podfile:
    CordovaPluginsStatic (from `../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins`) was resolved to 2.4.7, which depends on
      Firebase/Analytics (~> 7.0.0) was resolved to 7.0.0, which depends on
        Firebase/Core (= 7.0.0) was resolved to 7.0.0, which depends on
          FirebaseAnalytics (= 7.0.0) was resolved to 7.0.0, which depends on
            GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.0)

    CordovaPluginsStatic (from `../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins`) was resolved to 2.4.7, which depends on
      GoogleUtilities (~> 6.6) was resolved to 6.6.0, which depends on
        GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (= 6.6.0)

[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess capacitor.
        
        capacitor sync ios exited with exit code 1.
        
        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

**package.json**

```
"firebase": "^8.4.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.6.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.13.2",
```

**pod file**

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
use_frameworks!

# workaround to avoid Xcode caching of Pods that requires
# Product -> Clean Build Folder after new Cordova plugins installed
# Requires CocoaPods 1.6 or newer
install! 'cocoapods', :disable_input_output_paths => true

def capacitor_pods
  pod 'Capacitor', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/ios'
  pod 'CapacitorCordova', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/ios'
  pod 'CodetrixStudioCapacitorGoogleAuth', :path => '../../node_modules/@codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth'
  pod 'CapacitorAppleLogin', :path => '../../node_modules/capacitor-apple-login'
  pod 'CapacitorFirebaseAuth', :path => '../../node_modules/capacitor-firebase-auth'
  pod 'CordovaPlugins', :path => '../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins'
  pod 'CordovaPluginsStatic', :path => '../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins'
  pod 'CordovaPluginsResources', :path => '../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins'
  # Do not delete
end

target 'App' do
  capacitor_pods
  # Add your Pods here
  pod 'FirebaseCore' # Add this line
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging' # Add this line
end
```

Following things i´v tried without success:

- pod install --> leads to same error
- pod repo update --> runs without error but error is still there
- there is no podfile.lock in my project?

Do you have any hints for me?

Comment: what's your CocoaPods version?